# nodemailer 'From' header is missing

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I got this error in my sended mail box

```
host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.195.26] said:
550-5.7.1 [23.83.209.30      11] Our system has detected that this message
is 550-5.7.1 not RFC 5322 compliant: 550-5.7.1 'From' header is missing.
550-5.7.1 To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message has been
550-5.7.1 blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.1
https://support.google.com/mail/?p=RfcMessageNonCompliant 550 5.7.1 and
review RFC 5322 specifications for more information. d15si13788945pgv.519 -
gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

here is my code, I try to send an email from hosting with nodemailer

```
exports.main = ()=>{
  return transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "melisandre.id.rapidplex.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: 'YOI AKUAKULTUR <noreply@yoiakuakultur.com>', // generated ethereal user
      pass: 'xxxxxxxxx', // generated ethereal password
    },
  })
}

exports.register = async (nama, username, token)=>{
    let transporter = await this.main();
    let info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: 'YOI AKUAKULTUR <noreply@yoiakuakultur.com>', // sender address
        to: username, // list of receivers
        subject: "Akun anda telah diverifikasi", // Subject line
        text: "Aktivasi Akun Anda", // plain text body
        html: 'test email', // html body
      });
      transporter.sendMail(info, (err,res)=>{
        if(err){
          console.log(username)
        };
      })
}
```

that'is all detail I have, did you guys know how to fix it? it was okay before

Comment: This might be related to a missing or invalid spf record for your domain

Comment: how do I check that?